# Sending custom frame / packet in Python

Tags: python, networking

I read many articles and found how to send custom packet based on IP using socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW). But I want to send completely custom packet  starting from Ethernet header. I can't send ARP packet if I can't form Ethernet header cause ARP don't based IP. Please, help!
P.S. I am on Windows 7, not Linux :(

Comment: `socket.AF_PACKET` is what you're looking for, and whether it'll be available on your system will, at least used to, depend on your OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python, the easiest way is to use the cross-platform scapy library. It’s well known for that

[Scapy](https://scapy.net/)

You can sniff, send.... lots of packets, add your own protocols, use existing ones... and it works on nearly all platforms. (On windows, it uses Npcap/Winpcap)

You can then build an ARP packet using

```
from scapy.all import *
pkt = ARP()
pkt.show()
sendp(Ether(dst=..., src=...)/pkt)
```

Which will create such packets

```
###[ ARP ]###
hwtype= 0x1
ptype= 0x800
hwlen= 6
plen= 4
op= who-has
hwsrc= 00:50:56:00:1e:3d
psrc= 212.83.148.19
hwdst= 00:00:00:00:00:00
pdst= 0.0.0.0
```

To build the packet, use the / operator

```
ether = Ether()
ether.src = “00:00:00:00:00:00”
ether.dst = “ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff”
arp = ARP()
[edit arp.psrc, arp.pdst, arp.hwsrc, arp.hwdst]
packet = ether/arp
sendp(packet) # sens packet on layer 2
```

Have a look at its [Scapy documentation](http://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: Thank you! I have already used scapy, but I didn't try to import it in my programs.

Answer (score 0):

There's no cross-platform way to do what you want, of course.

Python is just passing these values through to the underlying C API. So, on a platform with a complete BSD sockets API including the `packet` interface, you can just use `AF_PACKET` and the other appropriate flags. (I think you'd want `ETH_P_ALL` or `ETH_P_802_2` rather than `IPPROTO_RAW`, or you might want `SOCK_DGRAM`… anyway, read your platform's `man packet` and figure it out based on what you actually need to do.) On Linux, at least most of these flags should be available on the `SOCKET` module; on other Unixes, they often don't get picked up, so you have to manually look them up in the system headers and use hardcoded constant ints in your code.

Unfortunately, if you're on Windows, this doesn't do any good. While WinSock has a feature they call [TCP/IP Raw Sockets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548(v=vs.85).aspx), accessed via `SOCK_RAW`, and recent versions of Python do expose this, it's just an emulation of a small subset of what actual BSD sockets implementations can do, and doesn't offer any way to go below the IP level (hence the name of the feature).

Microsoft's solution to this used to be that you'd write a TDI provider with the DDK, which would implement whatever protocol you wanted to expose as another WinSock protocol, and then your application-level code could just use that protocol the same way it would use, e.g., TCP. From the linked document above, it looks like this is obsolete, but the replacement seems like the same idea but with different acronyms (and, presumably, different APIs).

On the other hand, I'm pretty sure Windows already comes with protocols for ARP, ICMP, and anything other protocols needed for its usermode tools (because they obviously can't be written around raw packets). I'm just not sure how to access them.

---

As far as I know, the usual alternative is to use [WinPcap](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/default.htm).

While this was originally designed to be a packet capture library, it also implements a complete link-level socket interface that you can use for sending and receiving raw frames.

And there are Python wrappers for it, like [WinPcapy](https://pypi.org/project/WinPcapy/).

So, as long as you can require that the WinPcap driver be installed, you can write ARP code, etc., on Windows in Python. It's just different from doing it on Unix.

In fact, one of the examples on the front page of WinPcapY, "Easy Packet sending", should get you started:

```
from winpcapy import WinPcapUtils
# Build a packet buffer
# This example-code is built for tutorial purposes, for actual packet crafting use modules like dpkt
arp_request_hex_template = "%(dst_mac)s%(src_mac)s08060001080006040001" \
                           "%(sender_mac)s%(sender_ip)s%(target_mac)s%(target_ip)s" + "00" * 18
packet = arp_request_hex_template % {
    "dst_mac": "aa"*6,
    "src_mac": "bb"*6,
    "sender_mac": "bb"*6,
    "target_mac": "cc"*6,
    # 192.168.0.1
    "sender_ip": "c0a80001",
    # 192.168.0.2
    "target_ip": "c0a80002"
}
# Send the packet (ethernet frame with an arp request) on the interface
WinPcapUtils.send_packet("*Ethernet*", packet.decode("hex"))
```

Comment: Thanks! But I am on Windows 7 :( I was very disappointed when found out that AF_PACKET not supported o Windows. Can I do that I want on C ?

Comment: @ДенисМальований Windows has a completely different way to do this stuff under the covers, and its `SOCK_RAW` is just an clumsy emulation of part of the BSD raw sockets API that's just enough to send custom IP headers. IIRC, the recommended way to do what you want is to use the DDK to write a protocol and expose it through Winsock, and then your application code just treats it the same way they'd treat TCPv4 or whatever—except that I think Winsock already comes with ARP and other protocols, so you don't have to write them. But I'm years out of date and foggy on this stuff.

Comment: @ДенисМальований Or, instead of going Microsoft's way, I think a lot of people use [WinPcap](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/default.htm).

Comment: @ДенисМальований After a bit of research, I'm pretty sure WinCapy is what you want, not digging up Microsoft's ARP protocol or the like. See the edited answer.